# How to hide/show the Windows 8 taskbar on any monitor through .NET?

Tags: .net, windows-8, taskbar, user32

I have a personal application that allows me to hide and show the Taskbar in Windows.  It achieved this by making calls into user32.dll:

```
ShowWindow(int hwnd, int command)
```

Documentation for this API can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The issue I have is that obviously the taskbar has changed a bit in Windows 8 as it now extends across all your monitors.

Does anyone know if it is possible in Windows 8 to hide and show the taskbar (with code only) on individual screens and if so, how?

Comment: Use SHAppBarMessage() instead, the proper api to monkey with the taskbar.

Comment: Not programmatic, but you may not know: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/03/windows-8-moving-metro-around.html

Comment: Hans - I can't see how to use this API to remove the main windows taskbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching around for a long time for this, I decided to write my own.

I have uploaded it to Nuget.  It can be found here:

http://nuget.org/packages/BasicWindowsTaskbarManager

I doubt it's the most stable library in the world, but if you do have issues, just let me know and I'll see what I can do.